# Regex to remove spaces between numbers only

Tags: java, android, regex

I need to remove the spaces between numbers only, so that a string like this:

```
"Hello 111 222 333 World!"
```

becomes

```
"Hello 111222333 World!"
```

I've tried this:

```
message = message.replaceAll("[\\d+](\\s+)[\\d+]", "");
```

Doesn't seem to get it done.

Comment: What does that procedure do?

Comment: @stmfunk trying to extract phone numbers by reformatting all numbers into a single format, then extracting them

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
 String repl = "Hello 111 222 333 World!".replaceAll("(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d)", "");
 //=> Hello 111222333 World!
```

This regex `"(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d)"` makes sure to match space that are preceded and followed by a digit.

Comment: Yes that will also work, I thought lookarounds will perform pretty much same as captured groups. But I think this question is not about running performance benchmarks on both approaches, I could have edited my answer to include this option but now that other answer already covers it I will leave as it is.

Comment: And of course, there are places where the lookaround approach will work but the capture approach can't. Anyway, my point was primarily that the performance was (waves hands) enough the same for most purposes.

Comment: But as you can see here: `http://regex101.com/r/zL6yH3` that `1 2 3` can't become `123` with `(\\d) (\\d)`

Comment: @ anubhava: Doh! Well, that would be one of those places *"...where the lookaround approach will work but the capture approach can't..."* :-) I'd upvote the answer, but I did that before my first (now deleted) comment.

Comment: `(\\d) +(?=\\d)` and replace with `$1` should be fine too? if want to avoid a lookbehind

Comment: Brilliant! Just noting here that if the word immediately following the number also starts with a number, that's not handled correctly - _"Hello 111 222 333 20World"_ becomes _"Hello 11122233320World"_. For that, the pattern should be `(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d )` - with a trailing space in the second group.

Comment: For Javascript: `thestring.replace(/(?<=\d) +(?=\d)/g, '');`

Comment: Note: This regex (in Javascript) will throw a "Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name" in Safari because Safari does not support look behind. See stackoverflow.com/q/51568821/1066234 Use instead a lookahead like `thestring.replace(/(\d)\s+(?=\d)/g, "$1");`

Comment: @Avatar: This question was about Java hence lookbehind solution was given. Having said that modern Javascript also supports lookbehind but Safari is yet to be modernised.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
message = "Hello 111 222 333 World!".replaceAll("(\\d)\\s(\\d)", "$1$2");
```

Gives:

```
"Hello 111222333 World!"
```

Comment: This is a good solution for regex engines that do not support lookaround. In some cases you must run this function twice to replace all occurrences.