# Want to remove spaces within digits of a number in a sentence in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to delete spaces within a number in a sentence. e.g "My Request Number is 9 3 1 2 3 5 6 5" Should get converted into "My Request Number is 93123565". can someone provide a regex? I will use this in javascript. thanks

Comment: str.replace() should do it, look it up

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the regex string from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561026/regex-to-remove-spaces-between-numbers-only) similar Java question.

```js
const x = "My Request Number is 9 3 1 2 3 5 6 5";

const y = x.replace(new RegExp("(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d)", "g"), "");

console.log(y);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary! this is what i was looking for....working perfectly.

Comment: Why the downvote? :)

Answer (score 3):

**This Regex will do the job**.
It removes 1 **or more** spaces between digits.
[if you can use lookbehind, i.e. from ECMA 2018, which is supported from Chrome v62]:

```js
const oldString = "My Request Number is 9 3 1 2 3 5 6 5";

const newString = oldString.replace(/(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)/g, "");

console.log(newString);
```

This will also work in older browsers where lookbehind is not supported yet:

```js
const oldString = "My Request Number is 9 3 1 2 3 5 6 5";

const newString = oldString.replace(/(\d)\s+(?=\d)/g, "$1");

console.log(newString);
```