# How to remove spaces between numbers using python?

Tags: python, regex, numbers, space

I want to remove spaces between numbers using python. For example,

```
my_string = "take take , mouth ? 1 unit 1     2  3  1 mg 0 . 1 mg 1 . 1 mg 1 / 2 take . 5 unit and 00 . 5 unit"
```

My expected output is,

```
"take take , mouth ? 1 unit 1231 mg 0.1 mg 1.1 mg 1/2 take 0.5 unit and 0.5 unit"
```

**NOTE**: one zero was added before the decimal, and one was removed.

I have tried these,

[Regex to remove spaces between numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561026/regex-to-remove-spaces-between-numbers-only)

[How to remove multiple spaces between numbers using a single re.sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886798/how-to-remove-multiple-spaces-between-numbers-using-a-single-re-sub)

Thank you in advance.
But these doesn't for single digit numbers separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need not only removing spaces between digits but also `.` (dot) and `/` (slash), this can be accomplished as follows

```
import re
my_string = "take take , mouth ? 1 unit 1     2  3  1 mg 0 . 1 mg 1 . 1 mg 1 / 2 take . 5 unit and 00 . 5 unit"
no_spaces = re.sub(r'(?<=[0-9./])\s+(?=[0-9./])','',my_string)
print(no_spaces)
```

output

```
take take , mouth ? 1 unit 1231 mg 0.1 mg 1.1 mg 1/2 take .5 unit and 00.5 unit
```

`\s` denotes any whitespace (i.e. not only space, but also for example `\t`), you might elect to change it to   if you are sure you will only encounter spaces. `(?<=`...`)` and `(?=`...`)` are positive lookbehind and positive lookahead assertions, these are zero-length assertion and are used to made sure with only match spaces after digit/dot and before digit/dot, *without* matching said digits/dots. `.` when used inside `[` and `]` is literal `.` and thus does not require escaping.

To add leading zero before `.` followed by digit you can use again `re.sub` with zero-lenght assertion as follows

```
leading_zeros = re.sub(r'(?<=\s)(?=\.\d+)', '0', no_spaces)
print(leading_zeros)
```

output

```
take take , mouth ? 1 unit 1231 mg 0.1 mg 1.1 mg 1/2 take 0.5 unit and 00.5 unit
```

Explanation: put `0` between whitespace (`\s`) and literal dot (`\.`) followed by one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`). Observe that `.` needs escaping when used outside `[` and `]`.

For further discussion of used features read [`re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)